# How do I add privacy settings on macOS?

Tags: macos, privacy, apple-silicon

On my personal Mac (M1, Monterey) everything is ok, and the privacy settings look something like this:

[image]

There is a Screen Recording and Full Disk Access and so on.

Today at work, I was given the same Mac (m1, Monterey), BUT there are no such settings:

[image]

It feels like something is under-configured somewhere, but I didn't configure anything on my personal Mac for these settings to appear

I will need to share screen in Slack, but since there is no privacy setting (Screen Recording), then share screen does not work, the same problem with Telegram. But at the same time, the web version of Skype allows you to share the screen. But because of this, new items do not appear in the privacy settings.

I tried restarting the laptop, tried adding these files to `Library/Preferences`:

- `com.apple.screencapture.plist`
- `com.apple.screencaptureui.plist`
- `com.apple.screensaver.plist`

tried reinstalling Slack and Telegram, tried running the laptop in safe mode, but nothing helped.

Comment: Just asking the obvious: Did you scroll down in the list on the left? Your second screenshot does not demonstrate that there are no “Screen Recording” settings because that might be below “Diagnostic & Usage”

Comment: Yes, sure, i scroll down

Comment: As this is a work-assigned laptop it may be under MDM control, and so you may not be able to change certain settings or allow what you want it to do. You'll need to check with your IT dept...